# SQL - finding Sequence / Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a big event occurrence table. It has following columns:

- UserId
- EventId (Type of event)
- TimeStamp (When this event occurred)

I would like to know all the users that performed some event sequence between a date range.

If I am looking for events sequence 1-2-3... then event 1 should occur before 2 and 2 should occur before 3.

Currently I am just iterating over the record set using CLR stored proc. This approach is slow. Is there a better way to do it in SQL?

I am using SQl Server 2008. And there could be duplicate eventId per userId.

The Size of the table is around 3-4 billion rows and a date range could contain about 1 billion rows. Performance is critical.

Thanks

Comment: CLR means 2005/2008 -- which is it?  Could affect the answer.

Comment: Can there be duplicate eventID per UserId?  If so, how does this factor in to your logic?

Comment: What is the amount of rows likely to exist in the desired time period? and what are the indexes?

Answer (score 1):

If you can pre-know the sequence you're looking for, and it's not too long, you can SELECT the subset of the table you want (to deal with date range, and pick out one event ID), join as many copies of that to itself as needed, and then SELECT rows WHERE date(event1) > date(event2) AND date(event2) > date(event3).  It'd be a rather long query, which is why I'm not typing it out, but should work without being *too* inefficient.

EDIT: Example:

```
SELECT a.userID,a.date,b.date,c.date FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2 AND `type`=$type1) a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2 AND `type`=$type2) b ON a.userID=b.userID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2 AND `type`=$type3) c ON a.userID=c.userID
    WHERE a.date > b.date AND b.date > c.date
```

Comment: Size of table is around 3-4 billion rows.. and user could select a date range that consist of 1 billion rows.. this would require lot of memory and could be inefficient.

Comment: Ah, but you're also selecting the event type from that as well.  Since you're also joining on userID, it might not be that bad.  I'll edit in what I mean for that.

Comment: OK, I added an example of what I meant.  I may have made some kind of stupid mistake with it, but the subqueries should mean that with, say, 1000 event types, you're now only selecting 1M rows, joining that against another 1M rows (ok, that's still a lot), filtering by user ID (which should probably take it down some more), and then joining again.  You'd have to try it and see how it went.  If you had to, you could probably nest that farther to do the a>b date filtration before the second JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the exact sequence **at the time of writing the query** (either when you're coding it or when you caller code generates it dynamically), you can do this, as long as the sequence is not too long:

```
select *
from eventTable1 T1, eventTable1 T2, eventTable1 T3,
where t1.theTime between '01/01/2000' and '01/01/2001'
  and t2.theTime between '01/01/2000' and '01/01/2001'
  and t3.theTime between '01/01/2000' and '01/01/2001'
  and t1.theTime <= t2.theTime
  and t2.theTime <= t3.theTime
  and t1.eventId = 1
  and t2.eventId = 2
  and t3.eventId = 3
  and t1.userId = t2.userId
  and t1.userId = t3.userId
  and t2.userId = t3.userId -- Needed for performance reasons
```

This will work fairly well if you have an index on `userId, theTime` and the amount of rows is manageable for given time period (e.g. you don't get the full billion rows across a set of users)

Please note that the above can (and probably SHOULD) be further optimized depending on your data set and timeframe span, by first selecting ALL records for a given timespan into a temp table and then doing the above join on the temp table. This optimization works best if the amount of rows in a given timespan is manageable (e.g. <100k?) and there is an index on `theTime`

---

Another approach may be to avoid the `JOIN` and simply retrieve ALL the sequences combined, per user; and then do the "is this correct sequence" in the caller code:

```
SELECT * FROM eventTable
ORDER BY userId, theTime   -- works MUCH better if this is an covering index
```

And then in the caller code, you basically do a subset matching on per-user sequences (seems trivial to me but feel free to ask as a separate quetsion on SO if you aren't sure how)

Since this is pretty much per-user processing, you can avoid blowing out the memory by selecting chunks of users (approximate # of events per user, then grab as many users as would be safe for your memory - to have that work fast your SQL must support "TOP" or "LIMIT" syntax AND you should have pre-built list of all users in a temp table.

Comment: The data volume is very big... data transfer over the network would run in gigs.. To avoid this I am currently using CLR stored proc but it is slow as the logic is sequential.. I dont think I can do multithreading in CLR stored proc.. running another server to do multithreading on the same box is not an option..

Comment: @StackUnderflow - that is why I recomend having an indexed list of users (and an index on the user+time on main table), and then chunking by user. This way you can parallelize the app servers doing the data crunching, and have them request the data for the next batch of users when done.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

`select userid, eventid, theTime 
from eventTable 
where theTime between '01/01/2000' and '01/01/2001'
order by theTime DESC`

Comment: To get the items sorted by userid first, then date...change the order by line from "order by theTime DESC" to order by "userid ASC, theTime DESC"

Comment: Replacing each of the column names / table names and running it against a table that exists on my system returns the expected list.  Different Database engines are different (slightly)... which part seems "broken"?

Comment: @John K - the OP is asking for a list of certain events IN SEQUENCE (i.e. Eventid 1, 3, 4 in THAT ORDER) that occur in the history table.